# How I can convert my json data to html?

Tags: jquery

**I have get**

```
$.getJSON('ajax/ajax-test.php', function( data ) {
    ....
});
```

**json data I am trying view**:

```
{
    "1": {
        "section":"painting",
        "category": {
            "1":"african",
            "2":"modern art"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "section":"antiques",
        "category": { "3":"ikons" }
    }
}
```

How I can convert my json data to html to look like:

**painting**
  african
  modern art

**antiques**
  ikons

I tried

```
$.each(data, function(i, section_obj){
 $.each(section_obj, function(section, category_arr){
    content += category_arr+'<br />';
});
```

and

```
$.getJSON('ajax/ajax-test.php, function( data ) {
var content = '';
    $.each(data, function(i, section_obj) {
   $.each(section_obj, function(section, section_name) {
    content += section_name+'<br />';
            $.each(section_obj.category, function(category, category_arr){
               content += category_arr+'<br />';
            });
   });
  });
  $('#content-test').empty().append(content).css({ 'display':'block' }).show('slow');
});
```

but it not working!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you can access data, exmp: `alert(data[1].section)`.
if not then use: var data = `$.parseJSON(data)`

And only then try to use:

```
$.each(data, function(i, section_obj){
 $.each(section_obj.category, function(section, category_arr){
    content += category_arr+'<br />';
});
```

Comment: I get african, modern art, ikons - "category". I can not get "section"!

Comment: How youy trying to get a section?

Comment: $.each(section_obj.section, function(section, section_name){

Comment: Then read this: http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it

Comment: And this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html

Comment: tank yuo. I find get categories by $.each(section_obj, function(section, section_arr) {...}), but I can not associate $.each(section_obj, function(section, section_name) {...}) and $.each(section_obj.category, function(category, category_arr){..} what I can get section+categories. help me, please.

Comment: First rad what I gave you and you will have no problems. I dont want do do everyting for you. You have to learn by your self. Only becouse its basics.